# After installation of node and applying commanda for install node modules it will display this errors

Tags: node.js, node-modules, build-automation

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ncies":{"jscs":"^1.6.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\DHRUV SUTHAR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-24T06_01_23_323Z-debug.log

Comment: can you give us a little more explanation? like what code you're using to install node modules? what version of node you have? what is your windows version?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `npm cache clean --force`
See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html

Comment: Great @DhruvSuthar. If my answer is the solution so You should mark it as accepted answer. Thank you :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers